RHEL upgrade from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 by using ISO + upgrade an offline
We are working on Linux RHEL 7.9 ( VM machines ) in order to upgrade RHEL version to 8.6
We are using the ISO file - rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso since RHEL7.9 machines has no direct connection to the Internet
the problem is after we run the upgrade with the following
leapp preupgrade --no-rhsm --iso /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso

after preupgrade , we get the following report
============================================================
                      REPORT OVERVIEW
============================================================

Upgrade has been inhibited due to the following problems:
    1. Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.
    2. Newest installed kernel not in use
    3. Possible problems with remote login using root account
    4. Missing required answers in the answer file

HIGH and MEDIUM severity reports:
    1. Packages available in excluded repositories will not be installed
    2. Difference in Python versions and support in RHEL 8
    3. GRUB2 core will be automatically updated during the upgrade


Reports summary:
    Errors:                      0
    Inhibitors:                  4
    HIGH severity reports:       4
    MEDIUM severity reports:     1
    LOW severity reports:        6
    INFO severity reports:       4

Before continuing consult the full report:
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt

============================================================
                   END OF REPORT OVERVIEW
============================================================

before continue to the upgrade itself we fixed the following sections
1. Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.
2. Newest installed kernel not in use
3. Possible problems with remote login using root account
4. Missing required answers in the answer file

and then we run the upgrade as:
leapp upgrade --no-rhsm --iso /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso

when upgrade finished we reboot machine but machine does not started and stuck in single user mode
what we saw is something that we not understand, and this about the accessing the iso file - /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso during boot and maybe this is part of the problem
here a screenshot during boot

why machine try to access the ISO file? and if this is part of the upgrade then why the exception about - "Cant open blockdev"


because you're doing a Virtual Machine, don't do an in place upgrade on an existing rhel-7.vmdk file.  Instead create a new VM from some RHEL-8 version .iso.
My experience with the leapp upgrade is that it is not reliable... more often than not there will be some issue.  For example having GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = fips=1 in effect as a boot parameter prevents doing a leapp upgrade.  That an many other things, and with {my limited knowledge of} VM's there's the whole boot side of Linux to manage - which is generally not a problem when creating a new VM and doing a clean install of RHEL.  So it sort of does not surprise me you have boot problems from the leapp upgrade.
My suggestion {from knowing how my coworkers operate with VM's} is to create a new VM having a clean install of RHEL 8.x. Then migrate your data from your RHEL-7 VM as needed, and configure your RHEL-8 VM accordingly. I don't think I've ever had success with leapp anytime I've ever tried it. If you're totally ignorant of Linux configuration and run with 100% default RHEL Linux setup, then leapp probably works. But for anyone else who makes use of Linux and tweaks and customizes things (as Linux was intended) then leapp has issues.

I want to say about your note , the rhel 7.9 include application and data so we can't install  from scratch the OS what we need to do is upgrade from 7.9 to 8.6

if i understand your comment correctly... at some point in time your initial clean installation of redhat  did not include your application(s).  So you need to reinstall the application, and oftentimes the version that you had in rhel-7 will not run in rhel-8; there will be a new application version for rhel-8 which is what you should use.  So, if you are solely relying on your current rhel-7 version for everything without knowing how to reinstall and reconfigure applications then that's your real problem.

ALWAYS know how to get back to your current [functional] state by reformatting your disk(s) and reinstalling Linux cleanly from iso, and then reinstalling and reconfiguring correct versions of all your applications.
